# How to force stop count down clock when 1-4 seconds remaining? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a clock count down timer, all is working but only one problem is occurring.

When the time is 1 second to 2-4 seconds then if I click or navigate to other page in my website, then it will reset to 24 hours of time. How can I fix this issue?

Is there any way to achieve this? - I am fetching the duration to my table in my database and minus it with the local time now that I have in my timezone.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
// 1. JavaScript
var countDownDate = new Date("Aug 20, 2022 20:00:00").getTime();
var now = new Date().getTime();
// 2. PHP
//var countDownDate = <?php echo strtotime(''.$period['duration'].'') ?> * 1000;
//var now = <?php echo time() ?> * 1000;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  // 1. JavaScript
  // var now = new Date().getTime();
  // 2. PHP
  now = now + 1000;

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) - 6;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // if (hours < 0) hours += 24;

  var period_id = $("#period_id").val();
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> Due on: " + days + "d " + hours + "h " +
    minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  // if (distance < 0) {
  //     clearInterval(x);
  //     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  // }
  if (days < 0 && hours < 0 && minutes < 0 && seconds < 0) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-bell'></i>";
  }

  if (days == 0 && hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
    console.log("Ajaxing")
    return
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>submissions/lock",
      method: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data: {
        period_id: period_id
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-exclamation-triangle'></i> EXPIRED";
        return true;
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Could not get Data from Database');
      }
    });
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve] - please change the date to something that shows the issue

Comment: Hello sir, it's quite difficult to show or edit the time in real-time here because the issue persists if the user navigates or click to any links (for example: home or dashboard or any link you have) when the time is only 1-3 seconds then instead of expiring it resets to 24 hours BUT if the user waits until it becomes zero (0) the  it works fine. That's the issue

Comment: The PHP you give in comments does not produce the JavaScript you have above -- there is no `new Date` in the PHP `echo`.

Comment: Your code *explicitly* adds 24 hours. If you don't want that to happen, why do you have that code at all? Just remove that line?

Comment: @trincot - if I remove th `24` hours in the condition then the HOURS can sometimes become a negative value. I have only customized the computation of time which I minus it to 6 because it has additional 6 hours.

Comment: But what is the problem with negative hours? Further down the code you test for that condition and deal with it. The adjustment with 6 hours is not in the code you presented. And that seems more a "problem" related to bad time zone management.

Comment: For example: I am getting -5 hours instead of 19 hours. That's the issue with the hours.

Comment: If you get -5 hours then that means the count down date is in the past. Why would you add 24 hours to it? How does that make sense?